# Copy and paste multiple times from illustrator to photoshop

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

So this is the small issue I am having. I am trying to send an object from illustrator to photoshop, but I want to copy and past 2 versions one that is stroked and one that is stroked. The main problem I have is the paste in photoshop comes after I have done the 2 different versions. the P is the path item that is the outline. so it will paste two versions that have no stroke because it runs the first past after the second copy has already run.

```
function CreateLabel(Label)
{
    var P = Label.pageItems[0]
    app.copy()

     // get Print Area Width and Height and convert to inces at 300 DPI
    var LW = "\"" + String(Math.floor((Label.width/72)*300)) + "px\""
    var LH = "\"" + String(Math.floor((Label.height/72)*300)) + "px\""

    // create the new document
    var Cmd = "app.documents.add(" + LW + "," + LH + ", 300,\"Label\", NewDocumentMode.RGB,DocumentFill.TRANSPARENT);";  
    TellPhoto(Cmd)

    app.copy()
    TellPhoto('app.activeDocument.paste();')

    P.stroked = false
    app.copy()
    TellPhoto('app.activeDocument.layers.getByName(\"Layer 1\").remove();'  )

     //bt.body = 'BridgeTalk.bringToFront("illustrator");';
     //bt.send(5)
}; 

// paste the saved bit
function TellPhoto(Message)
{
    var bt = new BridgeTalk();  
    bt.target = "photoshop";  
    bt.body = Message  

    bt.onError = function(e)
    {  
        alert(e.body);  
    };

    bt.send(1);  
}
```

so I need something that will almost pause until photoshop has pasted the current clipboard in.

Comment: I have done some more testing with this. I thought maybe adding a $.sleep(10) might give me the pause I needed, but it did not. One idea I have is using while commands to halt the script and then wait for onReturn commands.

Comment: Still working with this. Small change to the system I used. I wrote out my steps in order and use a switch statement to pass through them.
so on return it will move to the next step now. I still have the problem where it sees paste as an unavailable command though.

Comment: still attempting this. I only do the copy and paste once, about 1 in every 50 runs It try to paste before the new document is ready and I get an error that "paste is not a valid command"

Answer (score 1):

I come across similar glitches from time to time with `app.copy()` and `app.paste()` commands. Quite often an additional pause (`$.sleep(200)`) before `app.paste()` helps. My guess is the app (Illustrator) just can't keep up to copy all the data by the time when another app (Bridge or even the same Illustrator) tries to paste it.